# How to include jsp files

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, maven-3

```
--webapp
     --WEB-INF
         --web.xml
     --index.jsp
     --jsp
         --Example.jsp
```

I am using javax.servlet

As I know ,the index.jsp is under the  of webapp .

But when I want to redirect to the Example.jsp ,It says could not found ...

How can I make it work?configure the pom.xml or the web.xml?

web.xml like this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>GetAccess</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.dodopipe.karl.GetAccess</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GetAccess</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/GetAccess</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

GetAccess.java

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Example.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: show us your codes please .

Comment: Can you show us code where you are redirecting? it should be something like this response.sendRedirect("jsp/Example.jsp");

Comment: Oh,thanks ,I forget the jsp...

Comment: @karlli, see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Your Example.jsp is under jsp folder, so your Request Dispatcher should be like this:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/Example.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```